# Noun clause as object

Tags: subordinate-clauses

I know I can use a subordinate clause as an object of a sentence.

I don't know who is that person.

Can I put this object at the beginning of that sentence

who is that person, I don't know.

Comment: No, you can't use a subordinate clause as an object. Your sentences are both ungrammatical. I suggest you need "I don't know who that person is", or the rather odd "Who that person is, I don't know".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A poem we all learn in high school is "[Stopping by Woods on a Snowy Evening](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/42891/stopping-by-woods-on-a-snowy-evening)," by Robert Frost. It begins:

```
Whose woods these are I think I know.
```

It's a simple and legitimate inversion of "I think I know whose woods these are." In common speech, such inversions are used for emphasis:

```
Whether she's coming I can tell you, but what she'll be wearing is still a secret.
```

The comma is usually unnecessary. In your sample case, I suggest "Who that person is I don't know." It's an indirect question, so the interrogatory form "who is" is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both *I don't know* and *I don't know X* work as full sentences. For that reason in

> *Who is that person, I don't know*

there is no indication that *know* has a predicate. So, it sounds like two separate sentences, the first a question and the second an answer.

One way to integrate them in that order into a single sentence could be

> Who is that person, is what I don't know.

In this one *is*, the second one, replaced *know* as the main verb. The subject is also no longer *I*, but it became *Who is that person*.

Comment: thanks for your reply. yea its true that these two sentences look different and are working differently.but if I write " what the task requires,he knows well". I think its working properly as object. what do you think

Comment: Your last sentence should be "Who that person is, I don't know", with subject-auxiliary inversion. "Who that person is" would then be a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question).